# Server side on Java with Netty and client on C++ or Objective C

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, netty

I'm making client-server app and we've chosen Netty as a connection management framework. We use SSL TCP connections. As of now, the client is also being made on Java. But in future the project should support mobile devices: Android and iOS.
The question is: how painful is to implement C++ or Objective C client connecting to Java server on Netty?

Comment: The choice of client server shouldn't matter. Once you have an TCP+SSL client or server it shouldn't matter what they are written in.

Comment: You can use web services to achieve this. I wouldn't say it's easy, but if it were easy we would all be out of a job! It's not too bad once you get up and running with the various technologies involved.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), I have used it as a client with server that implemented in Netty using a protocol I have defined that will send and receive data as JSON and it's as good as Netty.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what protocol you are using. If you define a protocol where you are sending serialised java objects as binary like [this](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/objectecho/package-summary.html) then you will trouble writing a client in a non JVM language. If you use a text based protocol (see [here](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html)) or a HTTP based web-service then it will be easy.

Comment: The main problem is not a format of data to send. We'll use JSON or similar. The problem place is management of socket connections from client-side: Netty library makes everything automatically on client-side controlling connection timeout and doing re-connections and everything like that. As I see, we'll have to implement all this things manually on C++...